# What is the distribution of the sample (empirical) KL divergence and can we use bootstrapping to approximate it?

Tags: bootstrap, sample, kullback-leibler

Let $p, q$ be two distributions, and suppose one can evaluate them pointwise.
Let  $\{x_i \}_{i = 1}^n$ be an IID sample from $p$, and let $KL_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \log\left[ \frac{p(x_i)}{q(x_i)} \right]$, the empirical $KL(p,q)$ divergence.

Q1: Clearly $KL_n$ is a statistic that follows some distribution. Do we know anything about this distribution for large $n$? In short what distribution does it follow? Some quick googling leads me to only the definition of KL and the empirical approximation.

Q2: Regardless of whether we can say/prove something in general about the distribution of $KL_n$, we can likely use bootstrapping to get an approximation for it. Namely, to sample $\{y_i: i = 1, ..., n\}$ from $\{x_i: i = 1, ..., n\}$ with replacement, then compute the empirical KL: $kl_y =  \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \log\left[ \frac{p(y_i)}{q(y_i)} \right]$. Doing this many (say 10,000) times will provide a bootstrapped sample of empirical KL divergences. I believe the histogram of the bootstrapped sample should be a good estimate of the distribution of $KL_n$ (for sufficiently large $n$). Is this correct, i.e., does this bootstrapping technique provide a sound way to approximate the distribution of $KL_n$?

Comment: This is a surprising formula, because it relies on the very $p$ that one is trying to estimate.  Wouldn't anything that deserves being called an "empirical" divergence use *estimates* of $p$ rather than $p$ itself?  Since you already stipulate $p$ and $q,$ the distribution is simple to describe: it's the sample distribution of the mean of the function $(p/q)(X)$ where $X\sim p.$ Again, since you don't seem to be estimating $p,$ there's no reason to bootstrap: just compute the distribution. Indeed, the particular data $x_i$ are irrelevant!

Comment: I used term "empirical KL" because it is a monte carlo estimate of the "real" KL, $\int_x \log (p/q)(x)dx$. Please advise if there is a better name. This term comes up in machine learning literature as KL-based loss functions are usually estimated as above.

Comment: @whuber presumably you mean "it's the sample distribution of the mean of the function $\log(p/q)(X)$ where..."

Comment: @whuber, thanks for helping frame this. I think that's what I'm asking--how do we "compute the distribution"? I think you mean compute the "density"?. If so, is this right: for each $x$ set $y(x) = \log (p/q)(x)$ then the density  is $f(y) = p(x) dx/dy$?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I inadvertently omitted the log.  Because you formulate a question about distributions, we cannot legitimately assume they have densities.  But your post is still quite confusing: bootstrapping has no place in a Monte Carlo simulation.  What would be the point?  You have two distributions and your goal appears to compute, somehow (such as with MC) their KL divergence.  *You don't even have (or need) any data.*